# How can I add chart data labels with percentage?

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I want to add chart data labels with percentage by default with Excel VBA. Here is my code for creating the chart:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'Sheet1'!$A$6:$D$6")
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlDoughnut
End Sub
```

It only creates Doughnut chart with no information labels.

Also, when I want to create another chart type with this same information how can I change the coordinates of the chart so it will not appear look like it overwrites the same one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to have Data Label in %:

```
            Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim Cell As Range
    Set Cell = ActiveCell
            Set Myrange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("$A$6:$D$6")

            ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
            ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Myrange
            ActiveChart.ChartType = xlDoughnut

            With PlotArea
                ActiveChart.ApplyLayout (6)
            End With

            With ActiveChart
                .Legend.Delete
                '.ChartTitle.Delete
                '.ChartTitle.Text = "Here goes your tittle"
            End With

        With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1)
            .Points(1).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            .Points(2).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            .Points(3).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            .Points(4).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        End With

    With ActiveChart.Parent
             .Height = 200 ' resize
             .Width = 300  ' resize
             .Top = Cell.Top    ' reposition
             .Left = Cell.Left  ' reposition
         End With

            End Sub
```

Second Type of Graph:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Set MyRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("$A$6:$D$6")

    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=MyRange
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered

    With PlotArea
        ActiveChart.ApplyLayout (2)
    End With

    With ActiveChart
        .Legend.Delete
        '.ChartTitle.Delete
        '.ChartTitle.Text = "Here goes your tittle"
    End With

With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1)
    .Points(1).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    .Points(2).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    .Points(3).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    .Points(4).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
End With

With ActiveChart.Parent
     .Height = 200 ' resize
     .Width = 300  ' resize
     .Top = 300    ' reposition
     .Left = 300   ' reposition
 End With

End Sub
```

And here you can find the color code:
http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/colors.htm

Comment: I see on top of percents numbers 1,2,3- how i could remove that?Also could i change the default colors @manu?

Comment: See my edit, and i put the line for the tittle as well

Comment: Yes cool it is working.What about have the colors set from default @manu?

Comment: I there a way of making colors of the chart by default what i need them to be?

Comment: @Anahit DEV see my edit, here the graph is all red, in the link that i put you can find the color code.

Comment: yes i see, it is working perfectly.One other question please @manu.How i could have multiple chart types with this same information.I created 3 or 4 command buttons but didnt know how i can create for each one chart type and made them work independently.could you help me with this please?

Comment: You want 3 or 4 different type of graph with the same data in one macro? Or you want to have one code for each command buttons? for the second option just change `xlDoughnut` by `xlXYScatterLines` or `xlLine`, ...

Comment: No i want separate charts maybe with different info,The issue is that i didnt know how to write the code for the second chart independently from the first one, so the second command button code will not affect the first one @manu. is that possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible. However you need to have separate code because each types of graph have different proprety.

Comment: Yes so for example how must be the next command button code with the second chart type, could you give me some example pls @maun ?

Comment: I added a second example which creat a column clustered graph

Comment: Yes great it works just one adjustment how i could change some coordinates for the charts cause it looks like it overwrittes the chart the one that exists, so if i could track and change the coordinates for each chart would be great.is that possible @maun?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98245/discussion-between-anahit-dev-and-manu).